# Adding a postDate with Guest Entries

Tags: guest-entries, postdate, comments

Is it possible to set the postDate for a new (disabled) entry created using the GuestEntries plugin?

Otherwise when posting a GuestEntry the postDate is not set until the entry is enabled or re-saved from Craft.

---

*Posting this with an answer as it may be useful to other people. If there are better ways to do this please add them.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a hidden field for your postDate to your GuestEntry form, e.g.

`<input type="hidden" name="postDate" value="{{ now|date("Y-m-j H:i:s") }}" />`

This adds the postDate using Craft's `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format.